# making some dynamic "executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate"

Tags: java, scheduledexecutorservice

This is my code and in this i have used "executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate" twice becoz I have one which want to run at Different period like after 2min and 3 min. So, instead of writing two line for same is it possible to manage this with single "executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate" with different period -

```
ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2);
executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TaskOne("https://Google.com/", "Google"), 0, 2,TimeUnit.MINUTES);
executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TaskOne("https://charlesreid1.com/wiki/Graphs/Guava", "Graphs"), 0, 3, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Comment: Why do you ask? You have one task which executes every 2min, the other executes every 3min. Why do you want to use a method which schedules two different tasks with two different periods in one method call?

Comment: 2min and 3min just a e.g. want to run the task based on different periods

Comment: You already do that with your code. What is the problem you have or what are you trying to do? Please [edit] your question to include a detailed description of the problem/issue.

Comment: Yes I already done. but here is only 2 periods i'm using. what if i have 100 periods then i'll have to write 100 time "executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate" statement in my code. so is there any way to pass the list of periods to "executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate" method.

Comment: No there isn't, but you can simply write a loop by yourself.

Comment: thanks it's work using loop.